# Chromium browser stuck on "About:blank" on Raspberry pi

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, puppeteer, pi

I got this JS code and i am trying to run it on my raspberry pi, It works great on my windows but not on my raspberry.

This is the code :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    async function Initialize() {
        return await puppeteer.launch({
            executablePath : 'chromium-browser',
            headless: false,
            args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-software-rasterizer",  "--disable-dev-shm-usage"]
        });
    }
browser = await Initialize();
this.page = await browser.newPage();

await this.page.goto('https://steamcommunity.com/login/home?l=english&oldauth=1');
await this.delay(4250);
try { await this.page.click('div[id="acceptAllButton"]'); } catch (e) { }
```

[image: THis is a picture on whats happening]

if i run this code

```
    async function Initialize() {
        return await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-software-rasterizer",  "--disable-dev-shm-usage"]
        });
    }``


i get "Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 113.0.5672.63). This can occur if either
 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npm install`) or
 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/pi/.cache/puppeteer).
"


I've tried update my system, reinstall node js to latest version, updgade puppeteer. I found another thread but there was no answear and it was posted 5 months ago.
```

Comment: What are you expecting instead? You never told it a URL to go to, so it's just showing the default startup page, which is in your Chromium settings.

Comment: Yes i do, i just cant share the whole code

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the default behaviour of a chromium browser controlled by puppeteer.

If you get a reference to the browser you have more control over the pages to which you can navigate to.

For instance:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch(/* Your options */);
  
// get the currently open pages and select the first one
const pages = await browser.pages();
const page = pages[0]

// Or create a new page
const newPage = await browser.newPage();

// Navigate to the desired site
await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
await newPage.goto('https://www.google.com');
```

Comment: It gets stuck on that and works perfectly fine on my windows when doing it with puppeteer.

Comment: i Changed the thread :), please take a look